# CFFI: TypeError: initializer for ctype 'char[]' must be a bytes or list or tuple, not str

Tags: python, ffi, python-cffi

Using the [CFFI library for Python](https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), I'm trying to coax a Python string into a char*, so that I can pass it to a C function that accepts char*.  I can't seem to figure out what the right incantation is.

Consider this example:

```
>>> from cffi import FFI
>>> ffi = FFI()
>>> ffi.new("char[]", "bob")
```

The result is:

```
TypeError: initializer for ctype 'char[]' must be a bytes or list or tuple, not str
```

The following does not work either:

```
>>> ffi.new("char*", "bob")
```

It says:

```
TypeError: initializer for ctype 'char' must be a bytes of length 1, not str
```

Comment: FYI -- I've included CFFI in the question title because there are other ways you can get this error in Python.  To my knowledge, this is the first time this has been asked with respect to this particular error and the CFFI library in Python.

Comment: Pick an encoding, and `"bob".encode('ascii')` your str - or use `b"bob"` if it's literal

Answer (score 15):

o11c solved this already:

Pick explicitly an encoding, e.g. `"bob".encode('ascii')`. This seems to be just necessary in Python 3.